# Splitting Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have searched all over the place to find out how to do this.

I have the following in my report so far:

```
   Page Header (Columns):
   Col1   Col2   Col3

   Details:
   D1     D2     D3
```

The page is currently set up as landscape and there is plenty of white space on the page. **I am looking for the easiest way (if possible at all) to get it to look like this**

```
    Page Header (Columns):
    Col1   Col2   Col3      Col1   Col2   Col3

    Details:
    D1     D2     D3        D1     D2     D3
```

Obviously in doing this the results need to follow on and not duplicate.

Hope this makes sense!

EDIT - I am using Crystal XI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve you should be able to do this using the Selection Expert. For your details section in there you will need to tick "Format with multiple columns". From there play around with the measurements in the Layout Options tab and you should be able to get this done. It's just a little fiddly.